# Setting up Gatsby blog hierarchical URL slug structure

Tags: javascript, html, url, hyperlink, gatsby

I am currently using the Gatsby Starter blog (https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-blog) - I can get this running locally without issue.

However I want to change the URL structure -

currently if I make a blog post called 'hello world', then the URL will be 'www.example/hello-world'. I want the URLs to be in the form of 'www.example/blog/hello-world'.

I've seen a few posts about changing settings in gatsby-node.js but nothing specifically addresses my issue. I am unclear what I need to change as both the Gatsby links API and web dev are fairly new to me.

Comment: I would recommend following this: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kzWIUX3CpuI&t=8610s). This video is exactly what you want. The working example is here: [link](https://cosmicspace.netlify.com/).

Comment: I did get ti working thanks to watching that video for a bit - thanks!

Comment: For future reference for anyone stalking - change 
`path: post.node.fields.slug` to `path: ``/blog${post.node.fields.slug}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change [this line](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-blog/blob/2a2f33cd544b4afa691082ef89e3180e433cd044/gatsby-node.js#L42)

```
    createPage({
      path: `/blog${node.fields.slug}`, // this line
      component: blogPost,
      context: {
        slug: post.node.fields.slug,
        previous,
        next,
      },
    })
```

Comment: Thanks - I realised it also needs to be changed in a few other places but this is the format I was looking for. Solved.

Comment: That's a great question - I can't remember off the top of my head but i'll have a look